# What does this via structure in Altium designer mean?

Tags: altium, via

I am looking at a complex PCB created by Robert Feranec. This board has 12 layers. I came across this via:

[image]

1. It looks like it contains rings and square plates. What do these mean?
2. It says "Simple" under "Via Stack". Is this actually only controlling how the stack is shown or selecting something other than "Simple" will change the via itself?
3. The name of this via is "Thru 1:12". But what does template "v45h20" mean?

Comment: I'm sure you can find out what v45h20 refers to if you study the picture more carefully.

Answer (score 3):

> *But what does template "v45h20" mean?*

- v = via diameter (or just via)
- 45 = 0.45 mm diameter
- h = hole size (or just hole)
- 20 = 0.20 mm

> *It looks like it contains rings and square plates. What do these mean?*

It has a square copper and solder resist but, like most holes, they are round and, the plating naturally assumes the same round shape.

> *It says "Simple" under "Via Stack". Is this actually only controlling
> how the stack is shown or selecting something other than "Simple" will
> change the via itself?*

Try it and see. I'm no expert on Altium (in fact I actually loath it) but I suspect it shows different views of the stack. It's in the preview area and will not change the actual via.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. It looks like it contains rings and square plates. What do these mean?

The image shows the copper connected to your via. Only planes and polygons are shown, no wires. For blind and buried vias it also shows the copper areas of the same net that are not connected.

> 2. It says "Simple" under "Via Stack". Is this actually only controlling
>    how the stack is shown or selecting something other than "Simple" will
>    change the via itself?

This setting changes how the via is defined:

- The copper diameter/shape/thermal relief is the same on every layer
- The copper is the same on each inner layer, but can be different on top and bottom
- The copper can be different on each layer

> 3. The name of this via is "Thru 1:12". But what does template "v45h20" mean?

As Andy aka wrote, these are there dimensions of the via. The templates allow you to use the same kind of via repeatedly in different places in the layout, or to copy the style from one board to another.